# Как ускорить парсер?

Tags: php, парсер

Для страницы пасится с помощью Simple_Html_Dom приличное количество информации, что значительно замедляет все процессы. Можно ли как-нибудь все это оптимизировать??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для продакшна исходя из производительности, лучше использовать нативную php-библиотеку классов DOM. Составление RegExp-паттернов для парсинга HTML/XML, а также использование библиотек на их основе (Simple HTML и т.д.), это [**зло!**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

[Класс DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php).

Минус: она чуть сложнее в освоении нежели Simple HTML DOM.

Плюс: Нативна (решение встроенное в php).

Вот ссылка на материал, где производят замер производительности различных библиотек парсинга html/xml:

[Сравнение библиотек для парсинга](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114323/).

Среди них, к примеру, "Nokogiri", является как раз-таки надстройкой над нативным php-решением. Правда, весьма простенькая, и потому, когда с ней столкнулся, решил писать свой парсер на основе DOMDocument, чего и Вам советую.

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае XML парсится двумя способами:

1. DOM парсер, когда весь документ засовывается в парсер и на выход подается дерево.
2. SAX парсер - потоковый парсер, когда парсится в виде потока.

SAX и быстрее и менее требователен к памяти. Недостаток SAX в том, что он только read-only и читает только в одном направлении - в остальном он хорош. Если эти ограничения вас устраивают юзайте SAX. Я думаю, что в PHP есть такой парсер (он есть во всех нормальных языках).

Сравнение обоих методов [здесь](http://idiotechie.com/?p=610)

Comment: я парсю html страницу

Comment: Да какая разница собственно говоря? SAX'у это все равно - он не проверяет на well-formness

Answer (score 1):

Да. Если нужна не вся информация - ручками написать регулярку. 
Еще быстрее - через JS, но это отнюдь не всегда удобно, так как приходится пересылать на клиентскую часть.