# Автоматический парсинг с сайтов

Tags: python, perl, php, ruby, синтаксический-анализ

Есть интернет магазин

И есть куча сайтов с которых нужно парсить информацию в автоматическом режиме

Как это вообще делается и что используется?

т.е. на php его сделать можно или будет все виснуть и вырубаться?

Так же нужно учесть что соединение будет через прокси

Ваши варианты, расскажите поподробней на чем вообще делается и как реализуется

Если есть примеры не стесняйтесь показывайте ;)

Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Для интерпретируемых языков, любое нативное решение или основанное на Си библиотеках (к примеру, LXML(Python)).

Скажу за PHP. Не буду повторяться, так как уже здесь на подобный вопрос отвечал.

[Как ускорить парсер?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/177469/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80)

Единственное что добавлю - "подтягивайте" данные CURL-ом или file_get_contents. CURL предпочтительнее:

[file_get_contents VS CURL, what has better performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance)

---

**UPD:**

Необязательно выводить данные в режиме RealTime, можно попробовать закэшировать их у себя на сервере - смотря на объем данных, которых вы подтягиваете.

Кэшировать также можно в RealTime, либо по Cron-у, если данные не являются "горячими", т.е. не нужны так уж сразу.

Если кэширование невозможно, то можно поступить иначе:

Тот блок, который необходимо подтянуть с другого сайта, запрашивать AJAX-запросом. php-функции sleep(), set_time_limit() или даже [ignore_user_abort()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ignore-user-abort.php) Вам в помощь. Некоторая информация про sleep ( **+** подводный камень с сессиями):

[What is a practical use for PHP's sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930736/what-is-a-practical-use-for-phps-sleep)

[session блокировки](http://www.askdev.ru/php/4288/session-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/)

Нынче существуют неблокирующие веб-сервера (их эмуляция, в том числе), которые работают в режиме **True FastCGI** (выделяют для операции отдельно взятый процесс (worker)). К примеру, **Nginx + PHP-FPM**, **phpDaemon**...

Про асинхронный RealTime-овый Веб, отвечал здесь:

[2-х секундное обращение к БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/170836/php-2-%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%B4)

Comment: для меня главное в первую очередь это скачивание html кода и чтобы в момент скачивания код никак не влиял на работу основного сайта (допустим вариант если скрипт повис и долго ждет ответа от сервера)

Comment: @dfhsfhgfj Я изменил ответ, ибо в формат комментариев не смог уместить весь свой поток мыслей.

Answer (score 1):

В тегах заметил ruby по этом напрпавлю на библиотечку [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) Парсит страницы, разберает их как DOM объекты.

Answer (score 1):

Ну раз в вопросе есть тэг **perl** — и на перле можно.

Скачать можно, например, модулем LWP или [LWP::что-нибудь](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/).

Можно взять [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) — в нём и парсер есть.